# Ionic 2 + AngularFire2 (TypeScript/JavaScript): Not able to properly iterate over Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ionic2, angularfire2

I am currently using Ionic 2 (which is based on Angular 2) to develop a Progressive Web Application about food and restaurants.

I use Firebase to manage my Users and more generaly as a way to save my data.

I also use the AngularFire2 library to communicate with Firebase.

The problem I am having right now is that have a list of dishes that my clients prefer that is saved in FireBase and I want to retrieve that in order to manipulate the data and use it in a certain algorithm to be able to make propositions on what menus the client could want to eat today.

I use this code to iterate over the FirebaseListObservable that has the user's preferences:

```
this.af.database.list('/users/'+this.authentificationService.getUserId()+'/favs')
      .subscribe(snapshots=>{
          snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
            this.prefList.push(snapshot.label);
          });
      });
  console.log(this.prefList);
```

And you can see that I push the values in that Observable into a list named prefList that I declared as follows:

```
 public prefList: String[]=[];
```

The console.log(this.prefList) line gives me this result (as seen from Chrome's inspect >> console) As you can see the array isn't empty.

[console.log(this.pref)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfaWF.png)

The problem is that I cannot iterate over the prefList because the length seems to always be 0. I tried with this.pref[0] aswell but this time I get Undefined. I really can't see a way to solve this. Please help?

Comment: Ok, so I think the thing that is driving me in the wrong direction is that the Chrome Console is printing in async which means I don't see the results in the way they are actually executed. I guess I'll have to move my code into a promise of some kind even though I'm not really familiar with the usage.

Comment: Yep, if you hover your mouse over the little `i` in the console output, you'll see "Value below was evaluated just now."